# Django - Deploy syncdb & South

Tags: django, deployment, django-south

I'm deploying a project on a new development environment.

As I'm using South I did:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb --all
$ python manage.py migrate --fake
```

I used `syncdb --all` to apply actual state of models.

Then `migrate --fake` to mark all models as migrated.

But after that, my model is not on the last version (missing fields)

What am I doing wrong ?

---

I assume all my modifications have migrations.

If I do

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

It seems to create the first state since when I used South (that is expected)
But then

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Some tables appears as already created

Comment: Does the app which fields are missing have migrations? Can you verify it has migrations for the fields you're missing? And does it work if you run `syncdb` and do a "real" `migrate` afterwards?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is to do not run `syncdb` at all and just use migrate? Does that work?

Comment: Can't work as no table exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this, should have been fine for my case

```
$ python manage.py syncdb --all
$ python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Having to redeploy my app recently, I faced the same issue.
I just realized that I had a double initial migration on the model that were causing the problem

```
0001_initial.py
0002_initial.py
0003_auto__add_field_mytable_myfield.py
```

I simply deleted & renamed

```
0001_initial.py
0002_auto__add_field_mytable_myfield.py
```

Then redone the whole database deployment (obviously not forgetting to update the already applied migrations on my other hosts)

Answer (score 1):

`--fake` option does not avoid errors while trying to create new migrations. It records that migrations have applied [without actually applying them.](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#options)

Also, you need `--ignore-ghost-migrations` or `--delete-ghost-migrations` to achieve what you are looking for.

To convert an existing project to `south`, you first need to [convert the app](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#convert-to-south)

Now, if you have already run `--fake`, to recover, you can do this:

- Go to `./manage.py dbshell`
- DELETE FROM south_migrationhistory WHERE id > 0; //Note that this would delete **everything** in the table.

If you want to remove migrations of a specific app,

```
DELETE FROM south_migrationhistory WHERE app_name = 'blah'
```

Comment: Thank you for the details. I'll check `--ignore-ghost-migrations` & `--delete-ghost-migrations` from the docs. I'm currently trying to deploy a new dev environment for a project already using south with many migrations in it. So my application is already southed, I'm starting from a fresh new database

Comment: So did you figure out what you were looking for?